# find all links that href value begin with "http..", then set target=”_blank“ fo it, use javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

what's wrong? `document.getElementsByTagName("a[href^='http']");`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.jsbin.com">jsbin</a><br>
  <a href="http://www.jsbin.com">aaaaaa</a><br>
  <a href="http://www.jsbin.com" target="_blank">zzzzzzzzzzzz</a><br>

<script>
window.onload=function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a[href^='http']");
  for (var i=0; i<anchors; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not use a selector like that with getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `querySelectorAll` function, not the `getElementsByTagName` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll